# Algorithm to maximize generated maze score

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, maze

I need to generate maze with 100x100 rooms. Each room connected only with 1 other room.

Here are example of correct 2x2 mazes:

```
+-+-+
|...|
+-+.+
|...|
+-+-+
```

And here are some incorrect 2x2 mazes:

```
+-+-+   +-+-+
+...+   |.|.|
+.+.+   +-+.+
+...+   |...|
+-+-+   +-+-+
```

For scoring our 100x100 maze we use following system:

There are 992 possible 2x2 submazes in our maze. We should count how many time each submaze occures and then use this formula:
$$1 + \ln\left(1+\sum\limits_i\frac{1}{|20 - a_i|+1}\right) $$

Where a[i] is occurence count of each submaze.

Now, my question is, how can I maximize this score?

I tried to use different maze generation algorithms (e.g. prim, backtracking, etc), but max score I'd got was around 6.05.

Maybe I can implement some kind of genetic or graph algorithm?